# How to prevent n+1 query many-to-many relationship in rails graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I am making a query in graphql without making a query n+1 in framework rails

This is to share the database, so that react-webpacker access the information.

I have avoided n+1 queries in one-to-one and one-to-many relationships with the batch-loader gem

one-to-many

```
BatchLoader.for(user.id).batch(default_value: []) do |user_ids, loader|
  Comment.where(user_id: user_ids).each do |comment|
    loader.call(comment.user_id) { |memo| memo << comment }
  end
end
```

one-to-one

```
BatchLoader.for(post.user_id).batch do  |user_ids, loader|
  User.where(id: user_ids).each { |user| loader.call(user.id, user) }
end
```

For the relationship many-to-many does not apply the above cases, I have tried the gem Shopify/graphql-batch, and its operation or result has not worked very well with one-to-many relationships

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

In this example scheme I want to get Physicians from a Patient

Answer (score -3):

The answer to your question is right [here in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHoddukdqf0). 
A few weeks ago, I was also curious about this then I stumbled upon this video.

The problem and the reason why you have n+1 query with graphql, according to the video, is that you are still trying to query the DB as if you are using normal REST API, where some of these query as been done for you by graphql itself so writing code for them results in double/multiple queries.

Take your time to watch the talk, you can find most of the answers you seek there.

Good luck!